# DropdownItem undefined in flowbite-react vite

Tags: reactjs, vite, flowbite

I am attempting to use flowbite-react on my react vite project but i got this error `Uncaught TypeError: DropdownItem is undefined` here is my tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "node_modules/flowbite-react/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      zIndex: {
        1000: "1000",
      },
      colors: {
        default: "#FDF5E6",
      
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("flowbite/plugin")],
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works now in the latest version:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/flowbite-react/v/0.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Manage to solved it by down grading to flowbite-react version ^0.5.0